# Change the Business Name to use the PrimaryReceiver's name in Preapproval interface for Adaptive Payments

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I would like to change the Business Name to use the name of the PrimaryReceiver. Is it possible via Adaptive Payments API?

[image: I want to change 'My Business' via API for each preapproval]

Comment: Try this: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/button-manager/integration-guide/ButtonManagerHTMLVariables/?mark=standard%20page%20style  HTML Variables for Displaying PayPal Checkout Pages

HTML variables for displaying PayPal checkout pages control how the pages appear and function. You wont be able to define or route this to a specific receiver if you're using chained; it will use the primary principle of the APP ID of the api call

Comment: I only found this option in the [Orders API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v1/) with `brand_name` but not in the [Payments API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v2/).